# Idris - proving equality of two numbers

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

I would like to write a function that takes two natural arguments and returns a maybe of a proof of their equality.

I'm trying with

```
equal : (a: Nat) -> (b: Nat) -> Maybe ((a == b) = True)
equal a b = case (a == b) of
    True => Just Refl
    False => Nothing
```

but I get the following error

```
When checking argument x to constructor Prelude.Maybe.Just:
        Type mismatch between
                True = True (Type of Refl)
        and
                Prelude.Nat.Nat implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method == a
                                                                                   b =
                True (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        True
                and
                        Prelude.Nat.Nat implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method == a
                                                                                           b
```

Which is the correct way to do this?

Moreover, as a bonus question, if I do

```
equal : (a: Nat) -> (b: Nat) -> Maybe ((a == b) = True)
equal a b = case (a == b) of
    True => proof search
    False => Nothing
```

I get

```
INTERNAL ERROR: Proof done, nothing to run tactic on: Solve
pat {a_504} : Prelude.Nat.Nat. pat {b_505} : Prelude.Nat.Nat. Prelude.Maybe.Nothing (= Prelude.Bool.Bool Prelude.Bool.Bool (Prelude.Interfaces.Prelude.Nat.Nat implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method == {a_504} {b_505}) Prelude.Bool.True)
This is probably a bug, or a missing error message.
Please consider reporting at https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues
```

Is it a known issue or should I report it?

Comment: Bear in mind that tactic-based proofs are obsolete in Idris, while a making decision to report an issue.

Comment: You might want to consider using `decEq`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at the implementation of the `Eq` interface for `Nat`:

```
Eq Nat where
  Z == Z         = True
  (S l) == (S r) = l == r
  _ == _         = False
```

You can solve the problem just by following the structure of the `(==)` function as follows:

```
total
equal : (a: Nat) -> (b: Nat) -> Maybe ((a == b) = True)
equal Z Z = Just Refl
equal (S l) (S r) = equal l r
equal _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! For `Nat` is easy since you can pattern match and procede by induction (I should have chosen another type for the example, probably...). What about `Int` or any other type implementing `Eq`?

Comment: `(==)` returns a boolean, so it can (in principle) return `False` all the time. How are we supposed to know that `a == b` entails `a = b` without looking at the implementation of `(==)`? With proofs, either your function must have  a sufficiently strong output type (like `decEq`) to convey its meaning or you'll need access to the body of the function.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using `with` instead of `case` (dependent pattern matching):

```
equal : (a: Nat) -> (b: Nat) -> Maybe ((a == b) = True)
equal a b with (a == b)
  | True = Just Refl
  | False = Nothing
```

Note that, as Anton points out, this merely a witness on a boolean test result, a weaker claim than proper equality. It might be useful for advancing a proof about `if a==b then ...`, but it won't allow you to substitute `a` for `b`.

Comment: @marcosh I think this should be the answer, because it works for 
`equal : Eq ty => (a, b : ty) -> Maybe ((a == b) = True)`.